# generic error GDI when creating image Files

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a problem with my webSite, I must create one image file for every record in my app.

In my IDE works fine, but I tested it in the IIS and I can't create the image files and I get the Generic Error GDI (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException)

The image folder have all W/R permissions, this is my Image Generator:

```
private void generador(string barCode)
{
    using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(barCode.Length * 40, 80))
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
        {
            // IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode INSTALADO en los fonts del servidor
            Font oFont = new Font("IDAHC39M Code 39 Barcode", 16);
            PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
            SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height);
            graphics.DrawString("*" + barCode + "*", oFont, blackBrush, point);


            bitMap.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/codigos/" + barCode + ".png"), ImageFormat.Png);
            bitMap.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

I have my data in a DataTable (just for testing) and when I iterate (calling repeatly generator), I have that error.

I repeat, in my IDE works perfectly, but when te application is published, I have this problem.

Please, anybody can help me?

thanks in advance.

best regards.

Comment: `System.Drawing` is not supported in web apps, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-most-common-technologies-not-supported-by-microsoft-8675c409bde2

Comment: Thanks a lot Lex Li, I didn't know about that.
I found NetBarCode and I could get what I want.

Comment: Now that the code works in IDE, have you tried to set app pool identity to local system? If it is not working,then GDI is limited by session instead of permission.

Answer (score 0):

As Lex Li said: "System.Drawing is not supported in web apps", Using it cause a LOT of problems. So I decided to use NetBarCode, and I could make it work:
- Install NetBarCode from nuget
- This is the code:

```
using NetBarcode; //Instalar NetBarcode de NugetPackages o usar la dll
using System.IO; // Filestream
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

private void generador(string codigo)
{
    var barcode = new Barcode("*" + codigo.Trim() + "*", NetBarcode.Type.Code39, true);
    var value = barcode.GetBase64Image();


    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/codigos/" + codigo.Trim() + ".jpeg"); //Generar archivo
    var bytess = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
    using (var imageFile = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        imageFile.Write(bytess, 0, bytess.Length);
        imageFile.Flush();
    }
}


protected void Bucle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Nif");
    dt.Columns.Add("Estudiante");
    dt.Columns.Add("Titulo");

    // Emulating my data
    // dt.Rows.Add("01769459"......)


    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        generador(row["Nif"].ToString());
    }



}
```

But if you want, you must control the memory stream, example (simliar), I use QRCoder.dll for it:

```
protected void Generar(string nif, string fileName)
{
    QRCodeGenerator qrGenerador = new QRCodeGenerator();
    QRCodeGenerator.QRCode qrCode = qrGenerador.CreateQrCode(nif, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgQrCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
    imgQrCode.Height = 150;
    imgQrCode.Width = 150;
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/files/" + fileName.Trim() + ".jpeg"); //Generar archivo
    Bitmap bitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);

    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }

}
```